# How to run multiple jetty instances

Tags: jetty, cluster-computing

How do you run multiple jetty instances without maven? I am using jetty jetty-9.2.15.v20160210. I did some google search for this and found 
https://sagarkarnati.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/run-multiple-instances-of-jetty-on-the-same-machine-with-different-ports/

But the version of jetty is 6 and the file structure in that version is totally different from 9.2.15. Does anyone have any idea?

I want to run two jetty instances on two different ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jetty 9, you will deal with $jetty.home and $jetty.base directory. Jetty advises to run jetty from $jetty.base directory.
 E.g. `C:/jetty = $jetty.home` directory and `C:/jetty/demo-base = $jetty.base` directory.
 You can specify which `$jetty.base` directory to use while running each jetty instance on the same machine.
 To solve this issue, I copied `$jetty.base` directory in `$jetty.home` directory and renamed it as `C:/jetty/demo-base-A`. 
 Before we can run two instances of jetty, make sure to change the port used otherwise we can run into port conflict issue. 
 Go to `$jetty.base/start.d/` directory and change `https.ini` and `http.ini` for port.